# Customizing django-allauth Login view

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-allauth

I am new to django and im trying to setup a login and signup page using django allauth. I successfully managed to do use with the help of various tutorials. However I want to customize my login page but at the same time I keep using the allauth code. Using the answer to this [**QUESTION**](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/3uykx8/customizing_djangoall_auth/), I have managed to make some progress but i still can't get to displaying any form fields on my template.
Basically I'm looking for an explanation for the code to the question identified above, but one is toned down to help a beginner.

This is the code that i currently have:

**My views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from  .forms import nibit_login

def login(request):
    context = {
        'login_form': nibit_login(),
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts_app/nibit_login.html', context)
```

**My forms.py**

```
from allauth.account.forms import LoginForm

class nibit_login(LoginForm):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['remember'].label = 'Stay signed in'
        self.fields['remember'].initial = True
```

**nibit_login.html template**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p> This is the login template </p>

        <form method="post" class="login-form">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ context.as_p }}
             <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

**This is what I am looking to be helped with:**

1. To get the form fields inherited from allauth Login form to show on my template so i can customize
2. Suggestion on how I can better customize a django-allauth Login form

Answer (score 2):

I've just come across this question looking for advice on customising the allauth login page.

I think your problem is that you're passing the context, but using the wrong keyword to reference the context in the template.

In nibit.html, try changing {{ context.as_p }} to {{ login_form.as_p }}